# Crystal xpath library or implementation

Tags: xpath, crystal-lang

Is there any way to use xpath when parsing an HTML file ?

I am looking for a Ruby Nokogiri equivalent but [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri) does not implement it ( yet ? ). Also tried [myhtml](https://github.com/kostya/myhtml) and [modest](https://github.com/kostya/modest) but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use external libraries for this! Crystal has an [XML module](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/XML.html) built in, which has [xpath support](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/XML/Node.html#xpath%28path%2Cnamespaces%3Dnil%2Cvariables%3Dnil%29-instance-method).

Here's a basic example:

```
nodes = XML.parse_html(html_content)
nodes.xpath_nodes(query).each do |node|
    # do something
end
```

where `html_content` is your HTML as a string, and `query` is your xpath query.

Comment: how to you use it ?

when I gave it a try it gave me some XML::Node but I could not get it to extract anything with an xpath call as it onlly returns empty strings. hq would get me the text that I need for the same call

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte Without code or specifics, I can't really help you. You should join https://gitter.im/crystal-lang/crystal to get some more real-time help with your code if it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

found one : [hq](https://github.com/maiha/hq.cr) from [maiha](https://github.com/maiha)

it implements xpath by wrapping the Crystal XML and myhtml and works well.

```
require "hq"
node = Hq.parse("<html><body><div>82 users</div></body></html>")
node.xpath("/html/body/div").text # => "82 users"
node.xpath("/html/body/div").int  # => 82
```